# SQL Query works in mySQL workbench but not in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a query that joins columns from two tables. I run the query without issue in mySQL Workbench, but when I run it in a sub in VBA it errors.

Here is the code for my DB connection

```
Sub dataquery()

Dim cntMyConnection As ADODB.Connection
Set cntMyConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim row As Long
Dim Col As Long

cntMyConnection.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}; server=localhost; port=3306; database=assignment3; Uid=root; pwd=1qaz2wsx3edc!QAZ@WSX#EDC; option=3;"

cntMyConnection.Open

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim src2 As String

src2 = **"select h.hunterID, h.year, h.hunted, h.harvested, m.sex, m.date_of_kill, m.gmu, m.horn_width, m.brow_tine_left, m.brow_tine_right, m.points_left, m.points_right from hunter as h inner join moose as m on m.hunterid = h.hunterid"**

rs.Open src2, cntMyConnection

If rs.EOF Then
MsgBox "No mathcing records found."
rs.Close
cntMyConnection.Close
Exit Sub

End If

row = 1
Col = 1

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Sheet2.Cells(row, Col).Value = fld.Name
    Col = Col + 1
    Next

rs.MoveNext

row = row + 1

Do While Not rs.EOF

Col = 1

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Sheet2.Cells(row, Col).Value = fld
    Col = Col + 1

    Next

row = row + 1

rs.MoveNext

Loop

rs.Close

cntMyConnection.Close

End Sub
```

I expect it to return the joined tables and populate the designated cells in excel.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: your loop get the field names over and over again, instead of the data...that's probably not your intention

Comment: Change to get the value....  Sheet2.Cells(row, Col).Value = fld.Value

Comment: ` range(1,1).copyfromrecordset rs`

Comment: You should remove that first `rs.MoveNext`, otherwise you'll skip the first record (unless you wanted to do that)

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I actually determined what was wrong. I ran the query within the schema in workbench, thus did not need to designate it in the code. I designated it in the code and now it runs perfectly.